# How to add two or more disk to softlayer virtual server while provisioning

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Add two or more disk to virtual server while provisioning in softlayer 
using rest query

Comment: Welcome to SO :-)
Please look at [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set the disk at order time, see the documentation about

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/createObject

basically you have to configure them at the block devices section:

```
{ 
    "blockDevices": [ 
        { 
            "device": "0", 
            "diskImage": { 
                "capacity": 100 
            } 
        }
        { 
            "device": "2", 
            "diskImage": { 
                "capacity": 25 
            } 
        }
    ], 
    "localDiskFlag": true 
}
```

Then you can add more disk after the Virtual server has been provisioned vi Upgrading the Virtual Server.

To upgrade the server you need to use this method:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder

see this example:

```
POST https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder

body: 
    {
        "parameters": [{
            "virtualGuests": [{
                "id": 49495232
            }],
            "prices": [{
                    "id": 2277,
                    "categories": [{
                        "categoryCode": "guest_disk1",
                        "complexType": "SoftLayer_Product_Item_Category"
                    }],
                    "complexType": "SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price"
                },

                {
                    "id": 2270,
                    "categories": [{
                        "categoryCode": "guest_disk2",
                        "complexType": "SoftLayer_Product_Item_Category"
                    }],
                    "complexType": "SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price"
                }
            ],
            "properties": [

                {
                    "name": "NOTE_GENERAL",
                    "value": "adding disks"
                },

                {
                    "name": "MAINTENANCE_WINDOW",
                    "value": "2014-08-25T9:50:00-05:00"
                }
            ],
            "complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest_Upgrade"
        }]
    }
```

basically you need to specify:

1. the ID of the VSI you want to upgrade
2. The prices of the items you want to add, to get the list of prices you can use this method:
   http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getUpgradeItemPrices
3. You need to specify the date when the VSI must be ugraded

Regards

Comment: Add two or more disk to virtual server while editobject in softlayer using rest query

Comment: you can not use the editObject to add more disks you need to use the placeOrder method to upgrade the VSI I updated my answer with an example