# Add SAN or Local disk to already provisioned Server in Softlayer using rest api?

Tags: java, cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I was trying to add SAN or Local disk to existing Server in Softlayer using REST API ,I searched in google but I can't get any solution and  got a solution in stack overflow but it was in ruby .

Can anyone tell how to frame it using REST API ?

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

In order to add new disk to the server you need to modify the server, that task can be done using Product_Order::placeOrder method.

Here you can see the example about how to modify the server:

[How to add two or more disk to softlayer virtual server while provisioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37782460/how-to-add-two-or-more-disk-to-softlayer-virtual-server-while-provisioning)

Regards